# Geo Data API - getAutocompletePredictions behaving wierdly

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am building an android app which is using Places.GeoDataApi.getAutoCompletePredictions method. I have followed this tutorial - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete

In an attempt to make this work, I have literally copied the code from this link. But somehow, my code does not execute after the line where this 'autocompletePredictions' method is called, i.e., does not work after line 169 in PlacesAutocompleteAdapter.java file in the example link above.

My code does not give any exception, nor any error, or any thing in log. It just does not execute after this line.

Can someone suggest what is going wrong? Did I not include any play-services in my gradle (I have included location-play-service:7.5.0)? or am I missing something in my manifest?

Please help. I have been scratching my head now for 2 days!

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer out. While setting up GeoDataApi, I was not using Locations.API. Also, the configurations in my AndroidManifest.xml was wrong.